# How much would votes sell for in early America?

Tags: united-states, election, colonial-america, money

I am reading an essay by Alfred F. Young right now in which the author mentions that Gouverneur Morris said of enfranchising those without property:

> Give the vote to people who have no property and they will sell them to the rich who will be able to buy them.

I find the concept of selling votes to be interesting, and I imagine that different elections would have different prices for which votes would sell. I have not been able to find any information on what the range of prices for votes would be, and it seems like a very difficult thing to put a price on. Is there any literature available on the prices which would have been payed for votes in various elections in the period?

Comment: I don't know about that era exactly, but corruption in Tammany Hall is fairly well documented, as it was under Huey Long (both in the early 20th Century). I vaguely remember reading a work of fiction for school (Upton Sinclair's *The Jungle* perhaps?) that recorded a character's stint buying votes. There are probably lots of other sources I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Prevention of buying votes with drinks was one of the reasons that establishments that sell alcohol were prohibited from opening on election day in most jurisdictions, until recently.

Answer (score 5):

In the 1980's, in Duval County, Texas, a 50 dollar food stamp voucher was the bounty if you voted "correctly" in a local election.

I only know this because a co-worker's aunt was busted, along with two associates, for this.  She had better lawyers and got the venue changed.  Two years probation. Her two 'associates' did time in jail.